# How to take unique values from file with vector in CPP using map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I have `vector` of some data type (Let's say-`int`) and I need to push back only unique values from the file? I am new to use STL. So i don't know how can i do it using `map` as i read that `map` only takes unique values. If I simply push back, then it will take all the values irrespective of its uniqueness.

Comment: If you use `std:::map` (or `std::set`), the keys (resp. values) will remain unique even if you set them several times.

Comment: An alternative to using std::set to do this is [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Answer (score 4):

The correct container to use for unique values is either `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`:

```
std::set<int> s;
s.insert(4); // s has size 1
s.insert(5); // s has size 2
s.insert(4); // s still has size 2
```

If you want to use `vector`, you'd have to maintain it sorted, which is a lot more code and work, and doesn't have the nice characteristic of `set` that everybody knows the contents are unique:

```
void add_value(std::vector<int>& v, int value) {
    // do a binary search to find value
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), value);

    if (it != v.end() && *it == value) {
        // duplicate - do nothing
    }
    else {
        // insert our value here
        v.insert(it, value);
    }
}
```

... or I guess you could delete the duplicates at the end using a rarely-used algorithm ([`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)) that will probably raise some eyebrows:

```
void uniqify(std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
}
```

**[UPDATE]** It has been pointed out to me that I completely misunderstood your question - and that you may have been looking for just which values occur exactly once - not a list of which values occur without duplicate. For *that*, the correct container to use is either a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` - so you can associate a count with a particular key:

```
std::map<int, int> keyCounts;

int value;
while (fileStream >> value) { // or whatever
    ++keyCounts[value];       // operator[] gives us a reference to the value
                              // if it wasn't present before, it'll insert a default
                              // one - which for int is zero - so this handles
                              // both cases correctly
}

// Now, any key with value 1 is a unique key
// what you want to do with them is up to you
// e.g., let's put it in a vector
std::vector<int> uniq;
uniq.reserve(keyCounts.size());

for (std::map<int, int>::iterator it = keyCounts.begin(); it != keyCounts.end(); ++it)
{
    if (it->second == 1) {
        uniq.push_back(it->first);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::set` maintains uniqueness at all times, and is easy to use but fairly slow. `std::sort`/`std::unique`/`erase` is a little more work, but generally quite a bit faster.

Comment: I think the question is asking how to get only the numbers which occurred once in the file... not just to cull duplicates out.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::map` will let you handle a *mapping* of *unique keys* to *some values* (which may or may not be unique). Math-wise, You may see it as a surjective function from the set of keys to the set of values of *your dataset*.

If your goal is to keep unique *indices* (or keys), then `std::map` is what you need. Otherwise, use `std::set` to store unique *values*.

Now, to keep only unique values from your dataset, you basically want to remove values which appear more than once. The simplest algorithm is to add values from the file as *keys* in a map, with its corresponding *value* being a counter for the number of occurrences of that entry in the file. Initialize a counter to 1 the first time the value is met in the file, and increment it each time it is met again. After having parsed the whole file, simply keep the *keys* whose values are exactly 1.

Counting the values:

```
template <typename key>
void count(std::istream &is, std::map<key,int> &map){
    while (!is.eof() && is.good()){
        key << is;
        auto it = map.find(key);
        if (it == map.end())
            map[key] = 1;
        else (*it)++;
    }
}
```

The above assumes that the `<<` has been overloaded to extract values from the stream sequentially. You will have to adapt the algorithm to fit your own way of parsing the data.
Filtering the resulting map to keep unique values can be achieved with `std::remove_if` and a function returning true when the counter is above 1:

The function:

```
bool duplicate (std::const_iterator<int> &it){ return *it > 1;}
```

The map filtering:

```
std::remove_if (map.begin(), map.end(), duplicate);
```